# How are connections differentiated from behind NAT routers?

Tags: linux, php, nat

Background: I have a very simple server program written in PHP. It's mostly working, but only as long as there is not more than one client per site.

Questions:

1. How does a NAT Router (typical SOHO router) know which internal client to send returning traffic?
2. What methods might I use to differentiate between multiple clients behind NAT routers?

Comment: ephemeral ports and routing/firewall tables.  Though not always using ephemeral ports, your simple web browsing example typically does.  While other traffic might use assigned source ports at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NAT routers would rewrite the source *orig-ip:orig-port* tuple of outbound UDP packets to *nat-ip:nat-port* and maintain a relations table between *orig-ip:orig-port* and *nat-ip:nat-port* so UDP answer packets arriving with *nat-ip:nat-port* as the destination could be mapped back to the *orig-ip:orig-port* destination. For details on how a NAT implementation might handle things, take a look at [how connection tracking is implemented in Linux](http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/theconntrackentries.html).

If your implementation does not allow for a changing client port number, it simply would not be guaranteed to work behind NAT routers. It might be working for one client as many implementations would try use the same source port number as the original packet's, if available, so so *nat-port* would be equal to *orig-port* for the first client's connection. But as this port becomes unavailable, subsequent attempts would inevitably lead to a condition where *nat-port* is different from *orig-port*.

So the basic "key" you would need to differentiate betwen different clients would be the client's source UDP port. Your server chat application needs to generate UDP packets going to the same destination port it received a client packet initiating the chat connection from - creating pretty much the same situation you have with established TCP sessions.

Comment: Thanks.  That is actually how I was hoping for it too work... what happens if you you have a network with hundreds of computers that might not have that many ports... err... not that its likely but... I'm just curious sir....

Comment: @user1833028 if the NAT gateway depletes the ports available for NAT, NAT can't be performed any more. But note that this is not going to happen except in rather limited circumstances (in the real world it is likely to happen if a large amount of users is running P2P software like BitTorrent) or with bad NAT implementations. Also, this is easily worked around by providing additional IP addresses for the translation to the NAT gateway.

Comment: What about ping packets, they don't have a source port, also why can't we have src mac as an identifier.

Comment: @Haswell Since ping packets have no ports, there is no need to NAT the ports, so there's no issue. The src mac is nearly useless as an IP identifier because it's not at the IP layer but at the ethernet layer. Consider, for example, if there's a router between the device running NAT and the device it's performing NAT for.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz client(192.168.0.10) -----[switch] ---- [192.168.0.1 Router 10.10.10.1]--google.com.
Another client 192.168.0.20 ---[switch]..... If only the IP address gets changed, how router will distinguish where to forward return packet if both clients start a ping. When we used port numbers, we knew which client IP associated with src port, but with ping we don't have that info.

Comment: According to RFC for NAT on ICMP, it uses ICMP identifier for the unique mapping.

Comment: @Haswell Yep, and that's precisely the same way hosts do it if there's more than one ICMP echo request outstanding. See RFC792 page 15 and RFC 1122 (Requirements for Internet Hosts) section 3.2.2.6 (particularly the paragraph that starts "Data received in an ICMP Echo Request MUST be entirely included in the resulting Echo Reply").

Answer (score 2):

The router for the 192.168.1.x network assigns each outbound connection a unique source port on the Internet side. When the router gets a reply, it looks up the port the packet was sent to in its NAT table and that tells it what IP and port to put as the destination on the LAN side.

When a packet is sent from the LAN side to the Internet side, the router checks its NAT table. If there's no entry corresponding to that local source IP address, local source port, remote IP address and remote port, one is created. A new destination port address is assigned. The packet is sent to the Internet with the source IP rewritten to the router's Internet IP and the source port rewritten to the assigned source port.

When a packet is received on the Internet side, the router checks the destination port in its NAT table. If there's no entry corresponding to that remote IP and destination port, the packet is dropped (unless something else the router is doing wants it). If it is, the destination IP address is changed to the correct local IP address, the destination port is changed to the original local source port, and the packet is sent to the LAN.

The "unique ID" you speak of is the combination of the remote IP address the local machine wants to communicate with and the local source port chosen by the router.

Comment: What happens to ping packets, they do not have a src port to begin with. Also, why can't we use mac address of client as unique Id ?